# Python/Pandas: How to remove Prefix And Suffix In A Name?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string

Names which contains honorifics like-

- DR. S.D. Milana Murthy
- V.A. Yakovlev Andrey

I want to remove all prefix and suffix from names specially all different kind of honorifics used in names in pandas.

Get output as

- Milana Murthy
- Yakovlev Andrey

My try:
`data['Name'].replace(['Miss ','Mr\. ','Ms\. ', 'Dr.'],'', regex=True)`

Output:

- S. D. Milana Murthy
- V. A. Yakovlev Andrey

Update:
How to replace some local letters to english.

Bjørn Larsen  ==> Bjorn Larsen, because for now pandas sees it is as Bj?rn Larsen

Comment: it seems your code removed `DR.`, as you want, no? (except I don't know how it works because of the capitals)

Comment: Indeed, but  i need to remove also V.A. etc, to get only First Name and Last Name

Comment: `V.A.` is not in your list. By the way you need the `str` accessor: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.